# SQL Unicode Regex to Filter Korean

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I am trying to filter out entries with Korean characters in the software version number column in a SQL table. I am trying to replace all entries that have Korean characters with 1.111.1. The issue is that every entry is now being converted to 1.111.1, even if it is a correct version number not meeting the Korean regex unicode requirement. What is causing this to make every value 1.111.1, and what is the correct way to filter the Korean values?

```
SELECT MachineName,CAST(SysStartTime AS DATE) StartDate,CAST(SysEndTime AS DATE) as EndDate,
        case
            When Version like '%[\uAC00-\uD7A3]%' then '1.111.1'
            else Version
            end as Version
        FROM table
```

Comment: Maybe `… like '%[가-힣]%' …`?  And `LIKE` comparisons are affected by collation…

Comment: could you try ... `like N'%['+  nchar(44032)+ '-' +  nchar(55203) +N']%'` ...

Comment: @JosefZ That worked, thank you!